# How to detect the system locale at compile time using gcc?

Tags: c, gnu-make

I'm using gcc to compile a C program (that is intended to be as portable as possible), and I have a separate module in which I define all the string constants I want to use.  These are then defined as external constants in an include file used by the rest of the code.

I would like to use a different set of string constants based upon the user's locale, and my current thinking is to simply define a symbol with the desired language settings and use the pre-processor to conditionally compile the appropriate values.  (Yes this does assume the user will be compiling the program themselves).

If I go down this route I can get the current language settings from the command line using

```
$ echo $LANG | cut -f 1 -d '.'
en_GB
```

but I have not managed to use this to define the symbol 'en_GB' (using -D) in a make file.

There may of course be a better ways to solve the problem!

It might be better to select the correct string constants at runtime but I don't want to have to update any of the source code other then the module the string constants are defined in.

Thanks

Comment: `but I have not managed to use this to define the symbol 'en_GB' (using -D) in a make file.` and this is your question? Because your question is `How to detect the system locale at compile time using gcc?`. The answer will be "is not possible", and you are stuck with you problem. Please do not ask XY questions.

Answer (score 2):

> How to detect the system locale at compile time using gcc?

It is not possible, in the way you want to do. `gcc` compiles code, it does not detect system locale.

---

Pass the locale with some prefix.

```
-DLANG_$(echo $LANG | cut -f 1 -d '.')=1
```

Then just check with preprocessor if the  macro is defined

```
#if LANG_en_US
stuff
#endif
```

To use shell script inside Makefile, you have to use shell.

```
CFLAGS += -DLANG_$(shell echo $$LANG | cut -f 1 -d '.')=1
```

Comment: This just defines LANG_ .  The output from make is 'gcc test.c -DLANG_=1 '

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't get the answer above to work Ended up defining ```LANG  = $(shell (echo $$LANG | cut -f 1 -d '.'))``` in the make file and using ```@gcc -D $(LANG) ... ```  The trick was using $$

Comment: `The output from make is` You may want to read Makefiles manual.